# My comment was deleted. Why?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange post: [How do we find the bandwidth of a bus?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399352/how-do-we-find-the-bandwidth-of-a-bus/699050#699050)

ISSUE: NOT a question BUT a conflict of response.

My comment was deleted.  The posted answer had factual and abbreviation inaccuracies.  Stack Exchange posting rules precluded my necessary clarifications. Why?

The "primary" answer to the Stack Exchange post said, "...1,000 MHz (1,000,000 times per second)..."

"Netspin's Inquiry":

1. grammatically a parenthetical explains what preceded it. "1,000 MHz...1,000,000 times (?) per second" [never in 64 years of my history in electricity/electronics has "times" ever been where "cycles" used to be]. FACT: cycles per second was replaced in 1960 with Hz. Prefix "M = 10^6"].
2. Also, that respondent makes an almost contiguous equivalency with "bps" and "Bps" which easily confuses his already mistaken orders of magnitude.
3. Stack Exchange suggests:
   a) "Anyone can answer" and,
   b) "Not to ask for help, clarification or responding to other answers."
   THEREFORE: As I noted, if anyone can answer a question then answers can not only conflict and worse be factually misleading or incorrect but the "right" answer is upward-voted, then how on earth can anyone have confidence in this most abstract yet pervasive of energy forms?
   Thank you.
   Please reply.
   P.S. Insulted by the almost spontaneous deletion of my comment and then battling my way around this website in order to find the reasoning for that removal, I believe I noticed something about being banned from the website altogether.  Then suggestions on how I could wiggle my way back if I posted "...good..." comments.  Of course good or bad could not be found as defined by Stack Exchange. So much more of an incentive to move on.
   Your full unfiltered comments are very much welcomed.
   RAC

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: The 'Answers' space below the Question up at the top of the page is for actual *answers* to that *question*. Yes, absolutely, "Anybody can answer" - but "answer" was not what you did. I can't see how your "answer" is even relevant to the question at all. TBH, I can't even make out what you're trying to ask in this question here...

Comment: I don't even understand what you were trying to do with that answer. It would have been deleted because it was put in the answer box, but even if it was a comment it makes no sense when paired with the question. I'm quite astounded you're confused about its deletion to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

The answer that was posted never even attempted to answer the question. This is a Q&A site